# Why response.sendRedirect() goes back to client browser

Tags: servlets, httpresponse

As we know, In servlet when we call response.sendRedirect() it goes back to client browser and asks for new request for new URL.
In an technical interview it was asked, "why" it goes back to client browser when we call response.sendRedirect()  ?
What can be expected answer for this "why" ?

Comment: On net found some details about sendedirect(). This can help one satisfy that person :- - After executing the SendRedirect( ) the control will not return back to same method.  The Client receives the Http response code 302 indicating that temporarily the client is being redirected to the specified location , if the specified location is relative , this method converts it into an absolute URL before redirecting.

Answer (score 2):

Q: How *else* could it possibly work?